# DateAdd function in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, dateadd

I am trying to use the `DateAdd` function in Access 2007.

My end goal is to have 5, 10, or 15 years added to the date coming in from the table if another field `[Type]` is a certain keyword.

For reference `NewDate = DateAdd("yyyy",10,[Type])`, and I know I'll have to come up with more code for the database to decide how many years to add to it.  Is this even possible in a query in Access 2007?

Comment: How I have it set up in my query is:  [Reinvestigation] = DateAdd("yyyy", 10,[Current]).   The [Current] field in my table will have three different values, {A, B, C}.  What my end goal is, so that I do not have to manually add in the date for [Reinvestigation] is to have this small algorithm take in the value of [Current] and based off of that value, for that particular person, output it into the [Reinvestigation] field either 5, 10, or 15 years in the future.  I hope that helps clear some things up!

Comment: How come, your Current field have A, B, or C? The third argument to the DateAdd function should be a date. If you could Edit your post with the right data in your table and show us the result you hope to see, we might be able to assist you further. With this limited information, it is not possible to nail down a solution.